# systemd resource management (specific case: mysql)

Tags: linux, systemd, ulimit, resources

I have a problem tying to figure out, how the resource management in systemd works.

To make clear where I am and how I got there, I should start with explaining my situation:

After migrating a mysql-db from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I have to deal with systemd. Not my first time and no problem till this day.
On 16.04 I noticed the log entry during mysql-startup:

```
Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
```

I found out, that the mysql-variable `max_open_files` (`max_open_files` is not set in my current config!) is dynamic, depending on 4 different scenarios (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit)
and in my case, obviously scenario no. 4 is used.

So my point is:
The mysql-config on 14.04 and 16.04 is the same, but it looks like the resource management acts different with systemd as it did on 14.04 (with `ulimit` & `/etc/security.d/limits.conf`)
The condition that mysql uses scenario no 4 is, that 'if operating system limit is Infinity' is true ... **why** is the operating system limit Infinity?

Another thing that I am struggling with:
If I define `max_open_files` in my mysql-config as lets say '1000' and have a look into `/proc/[myslq-pid]/limits` I can see that the soft-limit is set to 1000 and the hard-limit is 4096.

**Question 1**: Why is the limit 4096, as condition 4 from above hits true on 'if operating system limit is Infinity' ...

And I can set `max_open_files` to any value between 1 and 4096, and it defines limit - which is the expected behavior. But if it get set higher than 4096, it falls back to softlimit=1024 & hardlimit=4096.
I do not understand this behavior, because again, condition 4 from above hits true on `if operating system limit is Infinity` ...

That leads to my **Question 2**:
Where does this 'default value' come from?? And why I am not able to set the limit higher than 4096?

**Note**:
As soon as I define `LimitNOFILE=number` in the mysql-service-unit of systemd, 'number' gets set as soft AND hardlimit and I am able to define values higher than 4096. Confirmed by looking into `/proc/[myslq-pid]/limits` again.

I had a look into the docs of systemd, but for some reason the only thing that got mentioned in terms of 'defaults' are the `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` files, where I can define `DefaultLimitNOFILE=`, which is unset by default - so is there a `default Default`??

I seriously do not get behind this behavior... hope someone has a Tip on how to get this sorted.

I take any advice or hint you have!

I even would be happy to read more documentations, that explains this - but I just have not found the right ones ... everything I found leads me back to [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html), [setrlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) and [systemd/ControlGroupInterface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) which does not took me further than endig up here :)